# Error document configured in .htaccess file not work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, cpanel

On my cPanel account I have a htaccess file which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]   //for rewrite all .php file with .html extension

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R=301,L]   //for rewrite home page to url with index.html
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [R=301,L]  //for rewrite home page to url with index.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Problem is: when i open link like:
https://www.domainname.tld/test  ---> i have correct 404 error (page not exist)
https://www.domainname.tld/test.php or test.html  ---> i have default 404 error of Apache

This is very strange...

I contact cPanel support and they say me that not is a cPanel error
Can you help me?

Comment: This is because `RewriteRule` directive takes precedence over `ErrorDocument` .  Your server is reading `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]` instead of `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` when the request is for `file.html` .

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not with code inside htaccess but a config of cPanel! I disbale from WHM PHP-FM for interested domain (read here how to disable https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360049690354-How-to-Disable-PHP-FPM) because staff of cPanel explain me that was error. (read here https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050895654-ErrorDocument-directive-not-being-honored-when-using-PHP-FPM-and-the-filename-provided-has-a-php-extension)